# find specific change in file with Bazaar

Tags: bazaar

Is there a way to find a change in code using bazaar commands? Is it possible to search the first occurrence of a specific variable in the revision history for example?

Or are there any otherways? for example using rgrep or so?

Answer (score 3):

Use https://launchpad.net/bzr-grep plugin for this task.

Answer (score 0):

I just found history plugins for bazaar. I didn't give it a try, but have a look at:

http://doc.bazaar.canonical.com/plugins/en/#history-exploration